# What mime type do I use to allow users to download .bat from IIS?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, content-type, mime-types

Im trying to allow someone to download a .bat file so when they go to the url rather than it display as text on the page they are prompted to download but I cant figure out what mime type it is...

Ive looked in this list:

[List of iis mime types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx#EGAA)

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the file to be open in a text editor you could use text/plain otherwise you could use application/bat or application/x-bat, etc